# Converting JSON encoded in HTML to JSON using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I know similar questions have been asked here, but I'm still struggling to find a solution here.  I'm able to parse raw HTML from the bandsintown website, using beautifulSoup, but my ultimate goal is to access the script on the page and access a JSON embedded in the script.  Opening the page source, I can see that "eventsJsonLd" is what I need:

```
"jsonLdContainer":{"eventsJsonLd":[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-25","endDate":"2019-01-25","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100451456-pop-rocks-at-hopmonk-tavern-novato?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"HopMonk Tavern Novato","address":"Novato, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.1074198,"longitude":-122.5697032}},"name":"Pop Rocks","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Pop Rocks","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8532836.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/29109-pop-rocks?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8532836.jpeg"},
```

Here's my code:

```
#define url and build url array to cycle through webpages
page = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&page='
urlBucket = []
for i in range (0,2):
    uniqueUrl = page + str(i)
    urlBucket.append(uniqueUrl)

# dump response into an array
responseBucket = []

for i in urlBucket:
    uniqueResponse = requests.get(i)
    responseBucket.append(uniqueResponse)

#Make the 'soup'
soupBucket = []
for i in responseBucket:
    individualSoup = BeautifulSoup(i.text, 'html.parser')
    soupBucket.append(individualSoup)

# Build an array to hold script
allScript = []
for i in soupBucket:
    script = i.find_all("script")[4]
    eventsJSON = json.loads(script)
    print script
    allScript.append(script)



print allScript
```

Print allScript gives me the following:

```
[<script type="application/ld+json">[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100653596-e.r.n.e.s.t.o-at-the-endup?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"The EndUp","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7726402,"longitude":-122.4099154}},"name":"E.R.N.E.S.T.O","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"E.R.N.E.S.T.O","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8618862.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/4693798-e.r.n.e.s.t.o?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8618862.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239291-j.j.-grey-and-mofro-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"J.J. Grey & Mofro","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"J.J. Grey & Mofro","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/219177.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/2327212-j.j.-grey-and-mofro?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/219177.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239613-j.j.-grey-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"J.J. Grey","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"J.J. Grey","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/12437162-j.j.-grey?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239435-mofro-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"Mofro","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Mofro","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/71714-mofro?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100542800-brooke-heinichen-at-stuffed?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Stuffed","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7485824,"longitude":-122.4184108}},"name":"Brooke Heinichen","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Brooke Heinichen","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8921909.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/14944274-brooke-heinichen?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8921909.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012486121-william-fitzsimmons-at-hopmonk-tavern?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Hopmonk Tavern","address":"Novato, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.088489,"longitude":-122.553449}},"name":"William Fitzsimmons","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"William Fitzsimmons","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8852940.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/2450-william-fitzsimmons?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8852940.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100581554-kevin-paris-at-acoustic-yoga-@-yoga-source-los-gatos?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Acoustic Yoga @ Yoga Source Los Gatos","address":"Los Gatos, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.2358078,"longitude":-121.9623751}},"name":"Kevin Paris","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Kevin Paris","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8419497.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/1134314-kevin-paris?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8419497.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100692435-zak-fennie-at-black-stallion-winery?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Black Stallion Winery","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.35983179999999,"longitude":-122.2906388}},"name":"Zak Fennie","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Zak Fennie","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8851546.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/11843851-zak-fennie?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8851546.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100621943-frances-ancheta-at-off-the-grid-at-alameda-south-shore-center?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Off the Grid at Alameda South Shore Center ","address":"Alameda, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7712165,"longitude":-122.2824021}},"name":"Frances Ancheta","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Frances Ancheta","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8483059.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/7762254-frances-ancheta?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8483059.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013412612-pizza!-at-audio-nightclub?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Audio Nightclub","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.771362,"longitude":-122.413795}},"name":"Pizza!","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Pizza!","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/161356.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/198680-pizza!?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/161356.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100372855-ryan-scott-long-at-drake's-barrel-house?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Drake\u2019s barrel house ","address":"San Leandro, Ca","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7249296,"longitude":-122.1560768}},"name":"Ryan Scott Long","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Ryan Scott Long","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8671372.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3168705-ryan-scott-long?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8671372.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012999412-come-from-away-at-golden-gate-theater?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Golden Gate Theater","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7825715,"longitude":-122.4110742}},"name":"Come From Away","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Come From Away","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/13889714-come-from-away?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100441096-and-then-came-humans-at-drake's-brewing-company?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Drake\u2019s Brewing Company","address":"San Leandro, Ca","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7249296,"longitude":-122.1560768}},"name":"And Then Came Humans","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"And Then Came Humans","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8897159.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/13151463-and-then-came-humans?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8897159.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1011601412-man-go-at-el-rio?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"El Rio","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7467828,"longitude":-122.4193922}},"name":"Man-Go","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Man-Go","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3238684-man-go?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013320819-paul-mehling-at-freight-and-salvage-coffeehouse?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Freight & Salvage Coffeehouse","address":"Berkeley, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.8708715,"longitude":-122.2695117}},"name":"Paul Mehling","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Paul Mehling","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3307749-paul-mehling?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100672210-dj-spooky-at-catharine-clark-gallery?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Catharine Clark Gallery","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.76639,"longitude":-122.40704}},"name":"DJ Spooky","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"DJ Spooky","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/7060233.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/64476-dj-spooky?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/7060233.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012003162-craig-ventresco-at-atlas-cafe?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Atlas Cafe","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.73189,"longitude":-122.47615}},"name":"Craig Ventresco","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Craig Ventresco","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/139634-craig-ventresco?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100555258-rusty-jackson-music-at-kawika's-ocean-beach-deli?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Kawika's Ocean Beach Deli","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.774627,"longitude":-122.509993}},"name":"Rusty Jackson Music","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Rusty Jackson Music","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8250003.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/9978762-rusty-jackson-music?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8250003.jpeg"}]</script>, <script type="application/ld+json">[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100653596-e.r.n.e.s.t.o-at-the-endup?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"The EndUp","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7726402,"longitude":-122.4099154}},"name":"E.R.N.E.S.T.O","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"E.R.N.E.S.T.O","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8618862.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/4693798-e.r.n.e.s.t.o?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8618862.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239291-j.j.-grey-and-mofro-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"J.J. Grey & Mofro","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"J.J. Grey & Mofro","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/219177.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/2327212-j.j.-grey-and-mofro?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/219177.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239613-j.j.-grey-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"J.J. Grey","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"J.J. Grey","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/12437162-j.j.-grey?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012239435-mofro-at-uptown-theatre-napa?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Uptown Theatre Napa","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.2963465,"longitude":-122.2873698}},"name":"Mofro","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Mofro","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/71714-mofro?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100542800-brooke-heinichen-at-stuffed?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Stuffed","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7485824,"longitude":-122.4184108}},"name":"Brooke Heinichen","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Brooke Heinichen","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8921909.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/14944274-brooke-heinichen?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8921909.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012486121-william-fitzsimmons-at-hopmonk-tavern?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Hopmonk Tavern","address":"Novato, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.088489,"longitude":-122.553449}},"name":"William Fitzsimmons","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"William Fitzsimmons","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8852940.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/2450-william-fitzsimmons?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8852940.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100581554-kevin-paris-at-acoustic-yoga-@-yoga-source-los-gatos?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Acoustic Yoga @ Yoga Source Los Gatos","address":"Los Gatos, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.2358078,"longitude":-121.9623751}},"name":"Kevin Paris","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Kevin Paris","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8419497.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/1134314-kevin-paris?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8419497.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100692435-zak-fennie-at-black-stallion-winery?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Black Stallion Winery","address":"Napa, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":38.35983179999999,"longitude":-122.2906388}},"name":"Zak Fennie","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Zak Fennie","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8851546.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/11843851-zak-fennie?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8851546.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100621943-frances-ancheta-at-off-the-grid-at-alameda-south-shore-center?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Off the Grid at Alameda South Shore Center ","address":"Alameda, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7712165,"longitude":-122.2824021}},"name":"Frances Ancheta","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Frances Ancheta","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8483059.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/7762254-frances-ancheta?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8483059.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013412612-pizza!-at-audio-nightclub?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Audio Nightclub","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.771362,"longitude":-122.413795}},"name":"Pizza!","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Pizza!","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/161356.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/198680-pizza!?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/161356.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100372855-ryan-scott-long-at-drake's-barrel-house?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Drake\u2019s barrel house ","address":"San Leandro, Ca","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7249296,"longitude":-122.1560768}},"name":"Ryan Scott Long","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Ryan Scott Long","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8671372.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3168705-ryan-scott-long?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8671372.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012999412-come-from-away-at-golden-gate-theater?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Golden Gate Theater","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7825715,"longitude":-122.4110742}},"name":"Come From Away","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Come From Away","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/13889714-come-from-away?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100441096-and-then-came-humans-at-drake's-brewing-company?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Drake\u2019s Brewing Company","address":"San Leandro, Ca","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7249296,"longitude":-122.1560768}},"name":"And Then Came Humans","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"And Then Came Humans","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8897159.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/13151463-and-then-came-humans?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8897159.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1011601412-man-go-at-el-rio?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"El Rio","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.7467828,"longitude":-122.4193922}},"name":"Man-Go","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Man-Go","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3238684-man-go?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013320819-paul-mehling-at-freight-and-salvage-coffeehouse?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Freight & Salvage Coffeehouse","address":"Berkeley, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.8708715,"longitude":-122.2695117}},"name":"Paul Mehling","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Paul Mehling","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/3307749-paul-mehling?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100672210-dj-spooky-at-catharine-clark-gallery?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Catharine Clark Gallery","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.76639,"longitude":-122.40704}},"name":"DJ Spooky","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"DJ Spooky","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/7060233.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/64476-dj-spooky?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/7060233.jpeg"},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1012003162-craig-ventresco-at-atlas-cafe?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Atlas Cafe","address":"San Francisco, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.73189,"longitude":-122.47615}},"name":"Craig Ventresco","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Craig Ventresco","image":"","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/139634-craig-ventresco?came_from=244"},"image":""},{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","startDate":"2019-01-26","endDate":"2019-01-26","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100555258-rusty-jackson-music-at-kawika's-ocean-beach-deli?came_from=244","location":{"@type":"Place","name":"Kawika's Ocean Beach Deli","address":"SF, CA","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":37.774627,"longitude":-122.509993}},"name":"Rusty Jackson Music","performer":{"@type":"MusicGroup","name":"Rusty Jackson Music","image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8250003.jpeg","url":"https://www.bandsintown.com/a/9978762-rusty-jackson-music?came_from=244"},"image":"https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8250003.jpeg"}]</script>]
```

But, printing eventsJSON gives me an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I want to be able to build a new JSON based on specific attributes in eventsJsonLd, ie "startDate", "name", etc.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the script tag into `json.loads`, this is not  string but an object of the `bs4.element.Tag` class.

```
script = i.find_all("script")[4]
print(type(script))
```

Output

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

You need to get the `text` from the tag and pass it to `json.loads`

```
eventsJSON = json.loads(script.text)
```

Note:

The current url you try (https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&page=0) has the contents of that script tag as empty, i was able to get an output for a different url (https://www.bandsintown.com/a/29109-pop-rocks) of the same domain.

```
print(eventsJSON[0])
```

Gave an output

```
{u'startDate': u'2019-02-15T21:00:00', u'performer': {u'url': u'https://www.bandsintown.com/a/29109-pop-rocks?came_from=244', u'image': u'https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8532836.jpeg', u'@type': u'MusicGroup', u'name': u'Pop Rocks'}, u'name': u'Pop Rocks', u'url': u'https://www.bandsintown.com/e/100544648-pop-rocks-at-the-chapel?came_from=244', u'image': u'https://photos.bandsintown.com/thumb/8532836.jpeg', u'location': {u'address': u'San Francisco, CA', u'geo': {u'latitude': 37.7485824, u'@type': u'GeoCoordinates', u'longitude': -122.4184108}, u'@type': u'Place', u'name': u'The Chapel'}, u'@context': u'http://schema.org', u'@type': u'MusicEvent', u'description': u'Pop Rocks at The Chapel 2019-02-15T21:00:00'}
```